# Image in jquery mobile controlgroup item

Tags: jquery-mobile

I would like to have an image be displayed with each of the choices in a control group (in my case, radio buttons).  If I put each image inside the appropriate label, like so:

```
<li data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend>Choose a posting:</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="edit-DPOST_posting" id="edit-DPOST_posting-0" data-mini="true" data-theme="f"/>
        <label for="edit-DPOST_posting-0"><img src="my_img/iplacard.png" style="vertical-align:middle">INSPECTED (Green placard)</label>        
        <input type="radio" name="edit-DPOST_posting" id="edit-DPOST_posting-1" data-mini="true" data-theme="g"/>
        <label for="edit-DPOST_posting-1"><img src="my_img/rplacard.png" style="vertical-align:middle">RESTRICTED USE (Yellow placard)</label>
    </fieldset>
</li>
```

the entire group (including the legend) gets shifted to the right, as if leaving space for thumbnail images:

[image]

If I move the images before their respective `input` elements:

```
<li data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend>Choose a posting:</legend>
        <img src="my_img/iplacard.png" style="vertical-align:middle">
        <input type="radio" name="edit-DPOST_posting" id="edit-DPOST_posting-0" data-mini="true" data-theme="f"/>
        <label for="edit-DPOST_posting-0">INSPECTED (Green placard)</label>
        <img src="my_img/rplacard.png" style="vertical-align:middle">
        <input type="radio" name="edit-DPOST_posting" id="edit-DPOST_posting-1" data-mini="true" data-theme="g"/>
        <label for="edit-DPOST_posting-1">RESTRICTED USE (Yellow placard)</label>
    </fieldset>
</li>
```

then each image appears on its own line before the associated `input`.  If I put them after, they appear after each associated `input`.

If I leave the images out, everything displays fine, except that the images I want displayed aren't displayed.

How can I get the images to appear within each item in the group without the shift to the right?  I'm using JQM 1.4.2.

**UPDATE**: Not sure if this matters, but I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 and here is the surrounding context:

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
            <a href="index.html" data-transition="slide" class="ui-btn ui-btn-left ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon ui-corner-all">Back</a>
            <h1>ATC-20 Rapid</h1>
        </div>
        <div role="main">
            <form id="myform">
                <div id="mycolset" data-role="collapsibleset" data-filter="false">
                   <div data-editsec="post" data-role="collapsible">
                        <h2>Posting</h2>
                        <div><ul data-role="listview">
                        <!-- My <li> goes in here -->
                        </ul></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**UPDATE #2**: The only CSS other than what comes w/ JQM & themes generated by ThemeRoller is something which should not be affecting this:

```
@media all and (min-width: 30em) {
    .list-breakpoint img { border: solid #888 1px; }
    .list-breakpoint i { display: none; }
}
@media all and (max-width: 30em) {
    .list-breakpoint img { display: none; }
    .list-breakpoint a.ui-btn { padding-left: 1em !important; }
}
```

Comment: Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/VjJPPk, I am not sure I see the issue... Can you explain where exactly the shift to the right is?

Comment: We need to see your extra CSS. Can you edit my codepen to reproduce the issue?